# iText failure adding underlined text to PDF/A document

Tags: itext

When adding text to an existing PDF/A document everything works fine as long as the text is not underlined. If so, I get an exception:

```
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Path construction or drawing operators aren't allowed inside a text object.
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.moveTo(PdfContentByte.java:919)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.moveTo(PdfContentByte.java:904)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.writeLineToContent(PdfDocument.java:1615)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:1160)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:993)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(ColumnText.java:981)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.showTextAligned(ColumnText.java:1400)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText.showTextAligned(ColumnText.java:1418)
at de.arbeitsagentur.kiwi.common.drucken.itext.PdfUtils.stampVerworfen(PdfUtils.java:97)
```

Here's the code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, outputStream);
PdfContentByte over = stamp.getOverContent(1);
over.beginText();
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.WINANSI, true);
Font font = new Font(bf, 14, Font.BOLD | Font.UNDERLINE);
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("Hello World!", font);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(over, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, phrase, 67, 727, 0);
```

If Font.UNDERLINE is omitted, there is no problem.

My iText version is 5.5.13

Comment: 5.5.13 is a *maintenance* release of an old version of iText that is no longer supported. Maintenance releases are made for paying customers who can't migrate to the newest iText 7 releases. If you're a paying customer (you should be if you're distributing iText in a closed source environment), please use the closed ticketing system of which the URL was shared when you purchased a support agreement. (I think you are a customer, since you mention ATOS on your profile, and AFAIK Atos has a commercial license with us.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content on a page is defined using PDF syntax described in ISO 32000. If you use high-level objects in iText, you don't need to worry about the details: iText takes care of them.

iText also has a series of low-level methods that allow you to create PDF syntax. Every operator described in ISO 32000 has a corresponding low-level method in iText.

For instance: the `BT` operator can be added using the `beginText()` method, the `ET` operator can be added using the `endText()` method. These two operators `BT` and `ET` define a text object.

ISO 32000 tells you that only *text-state operators* are allowed in a text object. By underlining text, you introduce the *graphics-state operators* `m` (`moveTo()`), `l` (`lineTo()`) and `S` (`stroke()`). That is forbidden, and that is also what your error is telling you.

That's not the only problem, however. You have a `beginText()` in your code snippet, but you don't have an `endText()`, hence you are creating a text object that is never closed. This is in violation with ISO 32000.

Moreover, since you are using `ColumnText.showTextAligned()`, you don't need to create a text object. The `showTextAligned()` method does that for you. By adding an extra `beginText()`, you are nesting `BT` and `ET` operators, and that's in violation with ISO 32000 too, so please start by removing the line `over.beginText();` That line should never have been added there.

Finally, it was wrong to make underlining a property of a font. That's one of the many design flaws in iText 5 that eventually led to a complete rewrite of iText, resulting in iText 7.

It's much better to use `ColumnText.showTextAligned()` for the normal text, and then use `moveTo()`, `lineTo()` and `stroke()` to draw the lines. You know `Y` coordinate (727 - the distance between the baseline and the line you want to draw) the starting `X` position (67); you will need to calculate the end `X` position based on the length of the `String` (there are different methods that allow you to calculate that length).

Of course: if you'd upgrade to iText 7 (which has the same license as iText 5: either AGPL or commercial), you'll find it much easier to add text at absolute positions.

Comment: Yes. So I can cancel my answer in process... ;)

Comment: Sorry @mkl We should have a system to see who's in the process of answering so that we don't waste each other's time...

Comment: No problem. Happens seldom enough, so it's not really an issue... and I was only in line 3...

Comment: We already have such a system, the #slackoverflow channel on Stack. :)

Comment: Thank you Bruno for your explanation. I already had a over.endText() in my code, I just posted to the point where the exception occured. Now, I removed the beginText and endText. An upgrade to iText 7 is not an option at the moment, we still have to support Java 7.

Comment: iText 7 runs on Java 7, so the Java version shouldn't be an issue.